# Как работает childNodes

Tags: javascript, dom

Застрял, и не могу до конца понять, как всё-таки работает childNodes. У меня есть очень простая форма:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<form name="search">
    <label>Search the site:
        <input type="text" name="search">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

1. Сначала запрашиваю весь нодлист бади, в котором форму, можно найти по запросу `document.body.childNodes[1]` 
   и тут всё понятно.
   Но почему по запросу `document.body.childNodes[1][0]` выдаёт инпут? Я ожидал, что это будет пробельный символ "text". В крайнем случае label если text проигнорируется.

[image: Фрагмент кода из консоли хрома]

Comment: Если `document.body.childNodes[1]` это форма, значит `document.body.childNodes[1][0]` эквивалентно `document.body.childNodes[1].elements[0]` — этот массив содержит только инпуты и формы, но никогда не будет содержать других html-элементов или текстов

Comment: @andreymal, почему не ответом?

Comment: @Grundy потому что я не уверен, что я написал всё правильно (я только сейчас узнал, что к форме оказывается можно обращаться по индексу, лол)

Comment: @andreymal да, проверил, действительно при запросе document.body.childNodes[1].elements - нет никакого label. Могли бы уточнить, почему он выбрасывается?

Comment: @Макск потому что так задумали авторы веб-стандартов (а почему они так задумали, я уже не знаю)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. Уже нашел всю инфу на https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements 
честно говоря, было открытием и не совсем понятно, почему:
```document.body.childNodes[1][0] ``` работает как вы написали 
```document.body.childNodes[1].elements[0]``` а не 
``` document.body.childNodes[1].childNodes[1] ``` 

Вот именно это поставило в ступор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что

```
document.body.childNodes[1]
```

вернёт элемент формы

Сама форма представляет из себя псевдоколлекцию, в которой есть ключи на элементы формы (ключ = имя поля), а также ключи в качестве индекс (0 - первый элемент формы, 1 - второй элемент формы и т.д.)
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement

В Вашем случае, Вы обращаетесь к форме, а затем ко второму полю этой формы.

Если хотите получить текст из label, то Вам нужно написать:

```
document.body.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].textContent
```